# Flink sending same data to the same partition

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm getting data from kafka topic, then exploding array and producing multiple events using flatMap.

Incoming event format:

```
Event(eventId: Long, time: Long)
IncomingEvent(customerId: Long, events: List[Event])
```

Event format after exploding incoming event:

```
EventAfterExploding(customerId: Long, eventId: Long, time: Long)
```

These events will be written to the MySQL by using JDBC sink provided by Flink.

The data stored in the same Kafka partitions has the same customer id, that means I don't have any ordering issue here. But there can be lots of `eventIds` in an event, so that means there can be lots of events in the same flink partition after `flatMap` operation. This will cause latency or maybe OOM issues because one operator have to process more data. In order to prevent this issue, I can apply repartition or increase parallelism. But there is also one more concern here is that every `(customerId, eventId)` pair have to be sent to the same sink operator because there can be race condition issues if different writers try to operate same pair. For example;

```
event1 => EventAfterExploding(1, 1, 1)
event2 => EventAfterExploding(1, 1, 2)
```

In this scenario, database have to contains `event2` that has the latest time, but if these two data go to different sink partitions, `event1` can be in database instead of `event2`.

How can I solve race condition problem and scaling problem that happens when there are lots of data in the same partition? Does applying code block given below solves these problem? I though code given below, because after `keyBy` operation data will be redistribute and it will also guarantee that the same data will ben sent to the same partition but just want to make sure. Thanks!

```
incomingEvents
  .flatMap(new ExplodingFunction())
  .keyBy(event => (event.customerId, event.eventId))
  .addSink(JdbcSink.sink(...))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that code will have the effect you are looking for. All events for the same customerId and eventId will go to the same instance of the sink.